# Deploying rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger

I am trying to deploy a rail application which is in **/opt/rails/my_app**. 
To achieve this I have installed passenger gem and configured nginx using **passenger-install-nginx-module**. I can access the static welcome page, however when I try some other page like home (which is generated by rails generate controller home index), the browser keep waiting and waiting for response.

This does not happen when I deploy the application using `rails s` on port 3000.

**UPDATE**
When I execute `passenger-install-apache2-module`, I get **g++: unrecognized option '-R/usr/local/lib'**. I figured that I need to change '-R/usr/local/lib' to 'Wl,-R/usr/local/lib' in order to compile the LoggingAgent properly. Can you please tell me how to change the make file?

Comment: Do you see any activity in your `log/` directory for the environment you're using? Do you have any errors in your nginx log?

Comment: Nothing in error.log, however when I start passenger standalone I get the following. 
Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it
encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion
Passenger logging agent: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown
reason, with exit code 127 (-1: Unknown error)

Comment: Might be time to rebuild your Passenger and upgrade it to the latest version, 3.0.7. Either that or find a fix for that particular problem. Does it work in stand-alone mode?

Comment: standalone does not work, It is complaining that it can't find libcurl, however the library is in /usr/local/lib on my SUSE OS. I tried passenger on a test CentOS, which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding NGINX, it's sounding as though it's a permissions issue on some of your files and/or directories.  I would instead move the app to a dedicated /home directory.  For example, if you had a user named tester, your nginx.conf would say (the following works for me in Production:

```
server {
    listen       YOURIPADDRESSHERE:80; #use :443 if SSL is being used.

    server_name YOURFULLDOMAINNAMEHERE;
    #uncomment out following if ssl is used.
    #ssl on;
    #ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/private/YOUR_chained.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/YOUR.key;
    #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    #ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    #ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #ssl_ciphers    HIGH:MEDIUM;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    root /home/tester/YOURRAILSAPPNAME/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/YOURFULLDOMAINNAMEHERE-ssl_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/YOURFULLDOMAINNAMEHERE-ssl_error.log warn;
    location /home/tester/YOURRAILSAPPNAME/public/ {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page  404              /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Then make sure that your permissions are right (755 for all files, 644 for directories).

Answer (score 0):

In my previous work I spent so much time in process of deploying rails apps to vps productions, with different configurations  and gems,  and finally before 9 months I discovered [hatchbox.io](https://hatchbox.io) service for deploying rails apps. It was built by Chris from GoRails and believe me it saved me so much time and nerves. This is not advertising but really service works perfect and its not expensive.